# Create list of users who made first purchase between two dates

Tags: expresso-store, reports

I need to make a custom report of all customers who made their first purchase between 2 dates in expresso-store. I'm having aloof trouble working out the best way to achieve this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Store > Reports > Order Details. Set the range and export.

Comment: This only shows the order details, we need a report that shows who has ordered for the first time in a time period. So it will need to be a custom report.